# Eclipse Error:Target runtime jre1.8.0_31 is not defined

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkwBV.png)

I have imported one Maven project. During compilation of project I am facing some errors, which are described in image.
IDE version 
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600

Comment: You have not attached any image to this.

Comment: i have no permission to attach image you can click enter image description here link  image will be open.

Comment: How have you tried to resolve this?

Comment: I have check project/Targeted runtimes/jre1.8.0_31 is selected already and also checking selecting the show all runtimes but no solved

Comment: Have you tried running mvn eclipse just in case if your environment is correctly set there might be an issue with the dependency refresh.

Comment: and when i compile this project i get cannot access com.javainsight.interfaces.Bean
[ERROR] class file for com.javainsight.interfaces.Bean not found

Comment: sorry don't getting

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `.class` files are not generating. Try cleaning your workspace, then refresh maven dependencies in eclipse.
This will hopefully solve your problem, if your environment is properly set.

Comment: I Set Environment 
path:- \apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;
MAVEN_HOME:-\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9

I clean And refresh maven but still not working

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and to fix it I finally did a find/grep for the missing runtime name. This turned up `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` which contained a line `<runtime name="jdk1.8.0_66">`. I deleted that line and did a refresh on the module and everything was fine.

Comment: that did the trick! Many times thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got Project Build path and then select Targeted Runtime Select desire jre and apply the changes . After clean project everything worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the targeted runtime in the Properties of the project:

[image]